# Facebook Graph API: RSVP to Event

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, ios4, facebook-ios-sdk

I am trying to allow users to RSVP to events through my iPhone app (it is entirely events based), but i'm having some troubles. I have

I have tried these 3 methods:

```
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"EVENT_ID/attending" andParams:nil andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"EVENT_ID/attending" andParams:nil andHttpMethod:@"GET" andDelegate:self];
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"EVENT_ID/attending" andDelegate:self];
```

My test event ID is "216105945072171"

I get the same error for all 3: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (facebookErrDomain error 10000.)"

---

EDIT:

I got it working with this, however it feels like a hack of sorts. If anyone has a better solution, please post!

```
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"EVENT_ID/attending?method=POST&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN" andDelegate:self];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my experience, Facebook original API have some issue to produce ErrDomain.
Your issue may not occur to use another API as below:

http://www.capturetheconversation.com/technology/iphone-facebook-oauth-2-0-and-the-graph-api-a-tutorial-part-2